# datetime into mysql using android

Tags: java, android

How to get current date and time in android and insert into the mysql database... i am using EditText and trying to get the current date and time in it... but i cannot insert it... so anyone share your idea how to get current date and time in edittext and insert into mysql database...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());

tname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
tname.setText(currentdate);
```

trying to get the date....

```
private void registerUser() {
    String date =tname.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    register(date);
}
```

**Full code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText tname;
Button button;
private static final String REGISTER_URL="http://192.168.0.106/test/checkin.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());

    tname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    tname.setText(currentdate);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });
}

private void registerUser() {
    String date =tname.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    register(date);
}

private void register(String date) {
    String urlSuffix = "?date=" + date;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferReader=null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result=bufferReader.readLine();
                return  result;

            }catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
    RegisterUser ur=new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlSuffix);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code please.

Comment: The below answer is the entire code i used

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
// Parse the date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
Date selectedDate = sdf.parse("04-11-2018 01:10");

// then create the MySQL datetime string
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = sdf.format(selectedDate);
```

Comment: what is that fmt(format) it shows error for me(cannot resolve)

Answer (score 1):

Try using java.sql.date like this :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = formatter.parse(date);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());

insert(sqlDate);
```